# How to overcome \n(Enter) using charAt() and br.skip()?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

In this given program output is displaying blank for name.The reason is that we used `read()` and `readLine()` method is used.

```
//Employee details

import java.io.*;

public class Empdata {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // create BufferedReader object to accept data from keyboard
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // accept employee details
        System.out.print("Enter id:");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.print("Enter sex(M/F):");
        char sex = (char) br.read();

        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        String name = br.readLine();

        // display the employee details
        System.out.println("Id:" + id);
        System.out.println("Sex:" + sex);
        System.out.println("Name:" + name);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Enter id:10
Enter sex(M/F):M
Enter Name:id:10
sex: M
Name:

Comment: Don't use `<br>` to separate lines. If you want to post code use code-sample option (`{}` icon from editors menu).

Comment: It's not working properly for me,Why can't you edit and show me so that it would be so helpful for me to edit next time.

Comment: You can also use two spaces and then use `enter` button to create line break if you want to get same effect as `<br/>` and you are not inside code sample.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to edit your answer similarly (code should be in `code blocks`, not **bold text**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to overcome this problem :

1. `br.readLine().charAt(0)`
2. `br.skip(2)`

```
public class Empdata {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // create BufferedReader object to accept data from keyboard
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // accept employee details
        System.out.print("Enter id:");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.print("Enter sex(M/F):");
        char sex = (char) br.read();
        //Solution #1 : char sex = br.readLine().charAt(0)

        //Solution #2 : skip 2 characters if using (char) br.read()
        br.skip(2)

        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        String name = br.readLine();

        // display the employee details
        System.out.println("Id:" + id);
        System.out.println("Sex:" + sex);
        System.out.println("Name:" + name);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter id:10
Enter sex(M/F):M
Enter name:Vinay
id:10
sex: M
Name:Vinay
```